# Use esttab to generate summary statistics by group with columns for mean difference and significance

Tags: stata

I would like to use `esttab` (`ssc install estout`) to generate summary statistics by group with columns for the mean difference and significance. It is easy enough to generate these as two separate tables with `estpost`, `summarize`, and `ttest`, and combine manually, but I would like to automate the whole process.

The following code generates the two components of the desired table.

```
sysuse auto, clear

* summary statistics by group
eststo clear
by foreign: eststo: quietly estpost summarize ///
    price mpg weight headroom trunk
esttab, cells("mean sd") label nodepvar   

* difference in means
eststo: estpost ttest price mpg weight headroom trunk, ///
    by(foreign) unequal 
esttab ., wide label
```

And I can print the two tables and cut-an-paste into one table.

```
* can generate similar tables and append horizontally
esttab, cells("mean sd") label
esttab, wide label


* manual, cut-and-paste solution
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                              (1)                       (2)                         (3)                

                             mean           sd         mean           sd         
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Price                    6072.423     3097.104     6384.682     2621.915         -312.3         (-0.44)
Mileage (mpg)            19.82692     4.743297     24.77273     6.611187         -4.946**       (-3.18)
Weight (lbs.)            3317.115     695.3637     2315.909     433.0035         1001.2***       (7.50)
Headroom (in.)           3.153846     .9157578     2.613636     .4862837          0.540**        (3.30)
Trunk space (.. ft.)        14.75     4.306288     11.40909     3.216906          3.341***       (3.67)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations                   52                        22                          74                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

It seems that I should be able to get the desired table with one `esttab` call and without cutting-and-pasting, but I can't figure it out. Is there a way to generate the desired table without manually cutting-and-pasting?

I would prefer to output a LaTeX table, but anything that eliminates the cutting-and-pasting is a big step, even passing through a delimited text file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you still want to use esttab, you can play around using cells and pattern. The table in the original post can be replicated with the following code:

```
sysuse auto, clear

eststo domestic: quietly estpost summarize ///
    price mpg weight headroom trunk if foreign == 0
eststo foreign: quietly estpost summarize ///
    price mpg weight headroom trunk if foreign == 1
eststo diff: quietly estpost ttest ///
    price mpg weight headroom trunk, by(foreign) unequal

esttab domestic foreign diff, ///
cells("mean(pattern(1 1 0) fmt(2)) sd(pattern(1 1 0)) b(star pattern(0 0 1) fmt(2)) t(pattern(0 0 1) par fmt(2))") ///
label
```

which yields

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                              (1)                       (2)                       (3)                

                             mean           sd         mean           sd            b               t
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Price                     6072.42      3097.10      6384.68      2621.92      -312.26         (-0.44)
Mileage (mpg)               19.83         4.74        24.77         6.61        -4.95**       (-3.18)
Weight (lbs.)             3317.12       695.36      2315.91       433.00      1001.21***       (7.50)
Headroom (in.)               3.15         0.92         2.61         0.49         0.54**        (3.30)
Trunk space (.. ft.)        14.75         4.31        11.41         3.22         3.34***       (3.67)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations                   52                        22                        74                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't looked that closely at the `cells` options. This will come in handy everywhere I use `esttab`. Which is everywhere. Ben Jann should get a Nobel for `esttab`.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's a way to do this with `esttab` (`estout` package from `ssc`), but I have a solution with `listtab` (also `ssc`) and `postfile`. The table here is a little different than the one I propose above, but the approach is general enough that you can modify it to fit your needs.

This solution also use LaTeX's `booktabs` package.

```
/* data and variables */
sysuse auto, clear
local vars price mpg weight headroom trunk

/* means */
tempname postMeans
tempfile means
postfile `postMeans' ///
    str100 varname domesticMeans foreignMeans pMeans using "`means'", replace
foreach v of local vars {
    local name: variable label `v'
    ttest `v', by(foreign)
    post `postMeans' ("`name'") (r(mu_1)) (r(mu_2)) (r(p))
}
postclose `postMeans'

/* medians */
tempname postMedians
tempfile medians
postfile `postMedians' ///
    domesticMedians foreignMedians pMedians using `medians', replace
foreach v of local vars {
    summarize `v' if !foreign, detail
    local med1 = r(p50)
    summarize `v' if foreign, detail
    local med2 = r(p50)
    ranksum `v', by(foreign)
    local pval = 2 * (1 - normal(abs(r(z))))
    post `postMedians' (`med1') (`med2') (`pval')
}
postclose `postMedians'

/* combine */
use `means'
merge 1:1 _n using `medians', nogenerate
format *Means *Medians %9.3gc
list

/* make latex table */
/* requires LaTeX package `booktabs` */
listtab * using "Table.tex", ///
    rstyle(tabular) replace ///
    head("\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}" ///
    "\toprule" ///
    "& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Means} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Medians} \\" ///
    "\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}" ///
    "& Domestic & Foreign & \emph{p} & Domestic & Foreign & \emph{p}\\" ///
    "\midrule") ///
    foot("\bottomrule" "\end{tabular}")
```

This yields the following.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The answer chosen is nice but a bit redudant. You can achieve the same result with only estpost ttest.

```
sysuse auto, clear
estpost ttest price mpg weight headroom trunk, by(foreign)
esttab, cells("mu_1 mu_2 b(star)"
```

The output looks like this:

```
             mu_1          mu_2         b   

c_score     43.33858    42.034       1.30458***
nc_a4_17    4.007524    3.924623    .0829008*
```

Comment: Nice! One advantage of the chosen answer is that you can include moments not reported by `estpost ttest`.